# Setting portrait only splash screen in phonegap build config.xml

Tags: cordova, orientation, splash-screen

I want there to be only a portrait splash screen for my phonegap build app. So far I have only been able to find how to set the orientation for the whole app, not just the splash screen. What can I add to my config to do this?